# stick top progress bar in python to stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, progress-bar, stdout

How can I get in python a print to stdout with the progress bar pinned to the top to get a result similar to that with the "sudo apt upgrade" command on linux but with the elements that got printed one under the other but with the progress bar above. Im searching for a way to make the progress bar behave as sticky with z-index:999 on CSS.

```
Setting up python3-aiodns (3.0.0-2) ...
Setting up libpython3-all-dev:arm64 (3.11.2-1+b1) ...
Setting up python3-dev (3.11.2-1+b1) ...
Setting up theharvester (4.2.0-0kali2) ...
Setting up faraday (4.3.5-0kali1) ...
faraday.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up python3-aesedb (0.1.3+git20230221.9b7c468-0kali1) ...
Setting up samba (2:4.17.7+dfsg-1) ...
nmbd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
samba-ad-dc.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
smbd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Setting up python3-all-dev (3.11.2-1+b1) ...
Setting up kali-linux-headless (2023.2.5) ...
Setting up python3-pypykatz (0.6.6-0kali1) ...
Setting up kali-linux-default (2023.2.5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (252.6-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...

Progress: [ 99%] [#########################################################.]
```

I tried with this code:

```
import time

def print_progress_bar(iteration, total):
    percent = "{:.1f}".format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filled_length = int(50 * iteration // total)
    bar = "█" * filled_length + "-" * (50 - filled_length)
    print(f"\033[F\033[KProgress: |{bar}| {percent}% Complete")

for i in range(1, 101):
    print_progress_bar(i, 100)
    print(i, end=" ")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

but i can't print the numbers under each other.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to set different scrolling regions in the terminal. This can get a little complex, so I'd suggest using a library. The [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) progress bar does exactly this and pins any progress bars to the bottom.

For your example, you'd have something like this, but it's very customizable, so check the [docs](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io) for additional options.

```
import time
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
pbar = manager.counter(total=100, desc='Progress')

for i in range(1, 101):
    pbar.update()
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```